# Restore-SPSite error "0x80070003"

Tags: content-database, restore

I am getting following error when restore content database in SharePoint 2013.

> Restore-SPSite :
>   0x80070003 At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Restore-SPSite  http://SiteCollection/ -Path <"Path Name">
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:    SPCmdletRestoreSite)
> ```
>
> [Restore-SPSite], DirectoryNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS    ite
>
> Source Environment Build Version : 15:0:4763:1000 Destination
>   Environment build version : 15:0:4841:1000

Command I tried out to restore content database :

```
Restore-SPSite  "Site URL" -Path "<ContentDBPath>" -Force -DatabaseServer "DBServerName" -DatabaseName "ContentDBName"
```

Note : Here both Source and destination SharePoint 2013 installed in same SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

Restore-SPSite does not work across patch levels.  You will need to bring the source up to the same version.

Note:  this issue does not occur with the database attach method (Mount-SPContentDatabase) unless the mismatch is too great.

Edit:  There is no possible way to rollback.  It'll require a complete reinstall.

Comment: Thanks Greg for replying my post and i would like to rollback latest CU to my source environment,How to do it? this rollback is possible?

Answer (score 0):

**This issue typically arises when:**

> The content database has a schema version that is not supported in this farm.

To address this problem, ensure that the Configuration database version of the destination farm matches that of the source farm before backing up the content database from the source farm.

> Follow the instructions outlined in [This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/).

Answer (score 0):

From your command, it is not the content database backup rather a site collection backup.

For a site collection backup and restore both source and destination farm should be on same level.

As your source is lower version(4763) then destination (4861)in that case you do Content database backup and restore

- backup the content database in sql server
- restore it on awl server with different name(as you using same awl server for both farms)
- now attaché that's restored content db to Dev farm, during attaching it will upgrade the db version to Dev farm version.